# How do I teleport in the moderator headquarters?

Tags: chobots

In Chobots, how do I teleport myself in the moderator HQ?

Answer (score 1):

When you are a superuser you have to put in a special code to teleport yourself to the mod hq(thats how superusers teleport you too)

Hope that answered your question, if not please tell me.

Comment: Perhaps it'd help if you mentioned what this code is, or rather how to discover it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code for Loc Secret is #goto LocSecret.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a SuperUser, you type in a simple code to Teleport there.

Comment: and... superusercode its #global superUser=true